# BeanUtils with Maps

Tags: java, dictionary, javabeans, apache-commons-beanutils

How can I use the BeanUtils setProperty method with Maps.

For example, this method:
   public void setAddress(String type, Address address);
Can be setted using:
   BeanUtils.setProperty(beanObject, "address(home)", addressObject );

But if the object I want to set is a Map, is it possible? how?

Comment: This is what the BeanUtils user guide says:
"As an extension to standard JavaBeans APIs, the BeanUtils package considers any property whose underlying value is a java.util.Map to be "mapped". You can set and retrieve individual values via a String-valued key."
But I don't know how to make it work with a HashMap with a set(k,v) method

Answer (score 2):

Use the Map syntax `foo(bar)` (`bar` is the key of the map `foo`):

```
public static class Bean{
    private Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
    public Map<String, String> getData(){
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(final Map<String, String> data){
        this.data = data;
    }
}

public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception{
    final Bean bean = new Bean();
    // assign the foo key of the data property to the value 'bar'
    BeanUtils.setProperty(bean, "data(foo)", "bar");
    System.out.println(bean.data);
}
```

**Output:**

> {foo=bar}